# Highlight Predefined Words in Shiny DT table [Not through Search Highlight]

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm creating a shiny application and I want to highlight certain predefined words in DT table in shiny. I'm aware of the **search highlight** feature in DT. For example:

```
datatable(mtcars2, options = list(searchHighlight = TRUE, search = list(search = 'da')))
```

I want to highlight like the previous example but not from a **search**. For say, in **mtcars** data, I want to highlight words **'Merc', 'Fiat', 'Honda'** without providing it in the **search** of the table. As soon as the table appears, the words will be highlighted, not the entire cell.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please read and edit your question according to: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Add code for `shiny`, `DT` and example of  *predefined words*

Comment: Is cell that contains word highlight ok?

Comment: No, I don't want to color the entire cell. Only the word as I have really long texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tableHTML` for that:

```
library(tableHTML)
```

The `mtcars` dataset is use throughout this answer:

Create a `tableHTML` object using the `tableHTML()` function. Then apply conditional css, if the column (in this case the rownames, i.e. index `0`) `contains` a specific word. The css that is applied is simply highlighting the background using yellow:

```
mtcars %>% 
  tableHTML() %>% 
  add_css_conditional_column(columns = 0,
                             conditional = "contains",
                             value = "Toyota",
                             css = list(c("background-color"),
                                        c("yellow")))
```

The result is:

[image: result_1]

In case of many words that should be matched, you can create a vector of words:

```
words <- c("Merc", "Fiat", "Honda")
```

Create the basic `tableHTML` object:

```
tableHTML <- mtcars %>% 
  tableHTML()
```

And apply the css word for word using a loop:

```
for (word in words) {
  tableHTML <- tableHTML %>% 
    add_css_conditional_column(columns = 0,
                               conditional = "contains",
                               value = word,
                               css = list(c("background-color"),
                                          c("yellow")))
}
```

The result is:

[image: output_2]

If you only want to highlight a certain substring, you could modify the data and include a `span` around the substring and apply css there.

```
library(magrittr) # for the %<>% pipe

rownames(mtcars) %<>% 
  stringr::str_replace_all(c('Merc' = '<span style="background-color:yellow">Merc</span>',
                  'Fiat' = '<span style="background-color:yellow">Fiat</span>',
                  'Honda' = '<span style="background-color:yellow">Honda</span>'))


mtcars %>% 
  tableHTML()
```

The result is:

[image: output_3]

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to know if similar solution exists with DT table. I have to incorporate it within a shiny application and tableHTML is not supported by shiny.

Comment: You can use tableHTML with shiny, here is the vignette that explains it: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html

Comment: Well, thanks for sharing the documentation. But it colors the entire cell, I want to color the word only otherwise it doesn't make sense in my context.

Comment: it is possible if you are willing to insert spans. i have updated the answer with a possible workaround.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while but still I couldn't figure out how it would work on a specific column. I was trying out on **iris** dataset. This is the piece of code: `iris$Species %<>% 
  stringr::str_replace_all(c('setosa' = '<span style="background-color:yellow">setosa</span>',
  'virginica' = '<span style="background-color:yellow">virginica</span>'))

  iris %>% 
  tableHTML()` but this replaces the string with the span command

Comment: use `escape = FALSE` in `tableHTML()`