# Conditional styling of cells in a table based on a value range that differs per row (R)

Tags: r, html-table, styling, kable

I would like to create some tables in which the values from multiple columns get a conditional styling, based on ranges that differ for every row (and are specified in column 'min' and 'max'). As an example I created the following:

```
a <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
b <- c(20, 25, 40, 55, 60)
c <- c(60, 30, 80, 50, 60)
min <- c(15, 20, 40, 55, 55)
max <- c(25, 30, 50, 65, 65)

df <- data.frame(a, b, c, min, max)

a  b  c min max
A 20 60  15  25
B 25 30  20  30
C 40 80  40  50
D 55 50  55  65
E 60 60  55  65

table.df <- df[,1:3]%>%
      select(a, everything())%>%
      kable("html", escape = F) %>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left")
```

This gives me a table in which the columns for min and max are not presented (as I like). But I would like to add a conditional statement in which the values in columns 'b' and 'c' that fall outside of the range defined in columns 'min' and 'max' become red (or else the background of these cells). 
Not too familiar with styling tables, so any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at `kableExtra` [vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#celltext_specification) on HTML tables. There are examples there of doing something like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package tableHTML offers a lot of options for table styling, specially if you use some tricks with html code, for example one way to solve your issue would be the following:

based on the answer here [Highlight Predefined Words in Shiny DT table [Not through Search Highlight]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474117/highlight-predefined-words-in-shiny-dt-table-not-through-search-highlight/51474605#51474605)

You modify the data satisfying the conditions to include text formatting (or any other html formatting, font color, background color .....) and then pass it to `tableHTML()` with `escape=FALSE`

```
library(tableHTML)
library(dplyr)

a <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
b <- c(20, 25, 40, 55, 60)
c <- c(60, 30, 80, 50, 60)
min <- c(15, 20, 40, 55, 55)
max <- c(25, 30, 50, 65, 65)

df <- data.frame(a, b, c, min, max)

df %>% 
  mutate(b = ifelse(b < min | b > max, paste0('<font color="red">', b, '</font>'), b),
         c = ifelse(c < min | c > max, paste0('<font color="red">', c, '</font>'), c)) %>% 
 `[`(1:3) %>%
  tableHTML(escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, 
            widths = rep(50, 3), theme = 'scientific')
```

this would be the result

[image]

or maybe with two conditions and two colors:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(b = ifelse(b < min ,
                    paste0('<span style="background-color:#ccccff">', b, '</span>'), 
                    ifelse( b > max, paste0('<span style="background-color:#ff9999">', b, '</span>'), 
                            b)),
         c = ifelse(c < min , 
                    paste0('<span style="background-color:#ccccff">', c, '</span>'), 
                    ifelse( c > max,  paste0('<span style="background-color:#ff9999">', c, '</span>'), 
                            c))) %>% 
  `[`(1:3) %>%
  tableHTML(escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, 
            widths = rep(50, 3), theme = 'scientific')
```

You get :

[image]

The package offers a lot of formatting options and even conditional formatting (though not for this case), take a look here to see what else you can do with the package:

[tableHTML Basics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html)

[conditional formatting](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/conditional_column.html)

**Update**

There are many options to modify an unknown number of columns in a dataframe, I prefer working with the `apply` functions, like this for example:

Define a function to modify the columns:

(In this function `col`  is any vector, `min_col` is the vector containing the lower bounds, and `max_col` is the vector containing the upper bounds)

```
add_format <- function(col, min_col, max_col){
  if(!is.numeric(col)){
    return(as.character(col))
  }else{
    new_col <- ifelse(col < min_col | col > max_col, 
                      paste0('<font color="red">', col, '</font>'), col)
    return(new_col)
  }
}
```

and now apply this function on all columns in `df`, turn it to a `data.frame` and then the rest is the same

```
df %>% 
  sapply(add_format, df$min, df$max)  %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  `[`(1:3) %>%
  tableHTML(escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, 
            widths = rep(50, 3), theme = 'scientific')
```

You could also check out the functions `mutate_if` and `mutate_all`, they would work as well with some playing around

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would this mutate function work if I would like to have these conditions on a matrix with an unknown number of columns? I tried to include something like: df[,2:(ncol(df)-2)] in the ifelse statement, but this just results in errors.

Comment: Thanks! Almost there, only problem that now occurs is that the content of column A is replaced by the row number.

Comment: You probably have the column `a` as a factor then, just add `as.character` to the returned value in `if`, I added it to my answer